# Helm chart string split: cannot access map key

Tags: string, charts, kubernetes-helm, helper

I want to read env variables with a Helm Chart helper by reading the file line by line and split every single line in order to output them as valid yaml: `key: value`.

After splitting a single line the key is not accessible:

_helpers.tpl

```
{{/*
List env values from specified file
*/}}
{{- define "website.list-env-variables" -}}
{{- range .Files.Lines .Values.envFile }}
    {{- $envArr := split "=" . }}
    a: {{($envArr._0)}} <<<<<----------- error
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

error:

```
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: unknown object type "nil" in Secret.data.a
```

Without using the key (`$envArr`) the output is:

`a:   "map[_0:DB_PASSWORD _1:'my-secret-pw']"`

Help would be apreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

.env.dev

```
DB_NAME=database_name
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw
```

helm version

```
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.5.0", GitCommit:"32c22239423b3b4ba6706d450bd044baffdcf9e6", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.15.6"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to restore your operation, but no error was reported.

templates/_helpers.tpl

```yaml
{{/*
List env values from specified file
*/}}
{{- define "website.list-env-variables" -}}
{{- range .Files.Lines .Values.envFile }}
    {{- $envArr := split "=" . }}
    a: {{($envArr._0)}}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

values.yaml

```yaml
envFile: "prop/envFile"
```

prop/envFile

```
g=j
```

templates/configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}-v4
  labels:
    {{- include "test.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
data:
  {{- include "website.list-env-variables" . | nindent 2 }}
```

install: `helm install test .`

check: `kubectl get cm test-v4 -oyaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  a: g
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: test
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: "2021-12-13T06:20:16Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.16.0
    helm.sh/chart: test-0.1.0
  name: test-v4
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "738940"
  uid: ec09e1f5-2169-4958-ab41-fc13bca4bf9d
```

In summary, it seems that there is no obvious syntax error. You need to provide more information. Send out your `envFile`, where you use the `website.list-env-variables` template, and `values.yaml`.

ps. my `helm version`

```
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.7.0-rc.2", GitCommit:"4a7c306aa9dcbdeecf79c7517851921a21b72e56", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.16.7"}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. The output with your example is: `Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: unknown object type "nil" in ConfigMap.data.a`. I updated my answer with the requested env file data and the used Helm version.

Comment: I also installed helm v3.5.0 and used the envFile you provided, but still no error was reported. My system information. (```helm version```: version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.5.0", GitCommit:"32c22239423b3b4ba6706d450bd044baffdcf9e6", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.15.6"})(```uname -a```: Darwin appledeMacBook-Pro.local 20.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Wed Jun 23 00:26:31 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.2~5/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64)

Comment: Can you provide a file to use this template ```website.list-env-variables```?

Comment: After adding quotes: `a: '{{ $envArr._0 }}'` the output is: `a: 'g'`. Without, the error is there. I am running on Windows Powershell.